# Print the value in loop in Jquery ready function

Tags: php, jquery

somehow still not able to do what I’m inted to do. It gives me the last value in loop on click not sure why. Here I want the **value which is been clicked**.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var link = $('a[id]').size();
  //alert(link);
  var i=1;
  while (i<=link)
   {
 $('#payment_'+i).click(function(){
   //alert($("#pro_path_"+i).val());
  $.post("<?php echo $base; ?>form/setpropath/", {pro_path: $("#pro_path_"+i).val()}, function(data){ 
   //alert(data);
   $("#container").html(data);    
  });
 });
 i++;
   }
});
```

Here the `placement_1`, `placement_2` .... are the `href`s and the `pro_path` is the value I want to post, the value is defined in the hidden input type with id as `pro_path_1`, `pro_path_2`, etc. and here the `href`s varies for different users so in the code I have `$('a[id]').size()`. Somehow when execute and alert I get last value in the loop and I don’t want that, it should be that value which is clicked.

I think `onready` event it should have parsed the document and the values inside the loop
I’m not sure where I went wrong. Please help me to get my intended result.

Thanks, all

Comment: I can't see any placement_1, placement_2 - do you mean payment_1, payment_2?

Comment: yes i mean payment_1, payment_2 ...any way i got the soln by karim79

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the [`startsWith`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeStartsWith#attributevalue) attribute filter and getting rid of the while loop:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[id^=payment_]').each(function() {

        //extract the number from the current id
        var num = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];

        $(this).click(function(){    
            $.post("<?php echo $base; ?>form/setpropath/", {pro_path: $("#pro_path_" + num).val()},function(data){ 
                $("#container").html(data);    
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: hey thanks for the solun it worked like a charm  i did not had to a single change in the code ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a local copy of `i`:

```
$('#payment_'+i).click(function(){
    var i = i;  // copies global i to local i
    $.post("<?php echo $base; ?>form/setpropath/", {pro_path: $("#pro_path_"+i).val()}, function(data){ 
        $("#container").html(data);
    });
});
```

Otherwise the callback function will use the global `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a note on multiple/concurrent Asynchronous Requests:

Since you are sending multiple requests via AJAX you should keep in mind that only 2 concurrent requests are supported by browsers.

So it is only natural that you get only the response from the last request.

Comment: He's not sending simultaneous requests, but rather he's binding multiple click handlers each with different $.post parameters.

Answer (score 0):

What if you added a class to each of the links and do something like this

```
$(function() {
 $('.paymentbutton').click(function(e) {
  $.post("<?php echo $base; ?>form/setpropath/",
   {pro_path: $(this).val()},
   function(data) {
    $("#container").html(data);
   });
  });
 });
});
```

Note the use of $(this) to get the link that was clicked.